# Check Redeem status of Directory Invitation through Microsoft Graph

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I'm inviting a user to be added as a Member to my Active Directory using the Microsoft Graph REST API.

```
curl -X POST \
  https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/invitations \
  -H 'authorization: Bearer ey...Jg' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'content-type: application/json' \
  -d '{
  "invitedUserEmailAddress": "userInvite@hotmail.com",
  "inviteRedirectUrl": "https://example.com/afterInvite",
  "sendInvitationMessage": false,
  "invitedUserType":"Member"
}'
```

I do receive a correct response with the status field:

> "status": "PendingAcceptance",

which of course is true as the user has just been invited. Is there a way to see if the user has redeemed the invitation yet?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft Graph doesn't support to check the status for the invited users. However we can use the the **Azure AD reporting API** to check the this status.

To get this status, we can get the **Update user** event and check the **UserState** to achieve the goal.

More detail about Azure AD reporting API, you can this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-reporting-audit-events#update-user-attributes).

> **Note**:Actions don’t appear immediately in the audit activity log. It can take anywhere from 30 minutes to an hour to see the audit logs in the Azure portal from the time the operation is performed.
>
> Wait for 30 minutes to an hour and see if the actions appear in the activity log.

Comment: Thanks for your response Fei! I hope a status check to get info about the invitation will become a part of Graph soon.

Comment: Please make a request for this on Uservoice: https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/category/101632-microsoft-graph-o365-rest-apis

Answer (score 4):

I found it in the graph explorer:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?
  $filter=(UserType eq 'Guest') and (mail eq 'xx@yyy.com')&
  $select=externalUserState
```

Answer (score 2):

**Update**
Azure now has Invitation Status
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/b2b/customize-invitation-api#invitation-status

There is a property called "Source" under the Identity section of Azure Portal user profile and its getting changed to Microsoft Account or something like that from "Invited user" when the user redeem the invitation. But this source property is not in the User property returning from the API.

Find the request to implement way to do this in Graph API [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/32669014-give-us-a-way-to-verify-that-the-invitation-has-re) and please up vote it.

Comment: yeah so far there is no great way to do it. Upvoted the request

Comment: Finally they have added that! https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/b2b/customize-invitation-api#invitation-status

Comment: Even though Microsoft has provided this information now through powershel cmdlet, it will not work in the linux enviornment.

Answer (score 1):

we cannot use filter more than once. How about

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=mail eq 'usersemail'&$select=externalUserState
```

this can be done using ms graph API